# How do I determine the most swapped number of an array in selection sort?

Tags: c, sorting, swap, selection-sort

I made a program to do a **selection sort** and determine which are the most swapped elements of the array. For example, if the elements of the array = 8 12 6 9 1 3, the most swapped number is 8. It's swapped 2 times. For another case, how do I find the **most swapped number** and **how many times** did it swap?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int case, numbers, array[50], i,j,k,c,d, min,temp, swap=0;

//Number of cases
printf("case = ");
scanf("%d", &case);

//inserting the elements of array
for(i=0; i<case; i++){
    printf("total of numbers = ");
    scanf("%d", &numbers);

    for(j=0; j<numbers; j++){
        scanf("%d", &array[j]);
    }
    

    //Selection Sort
    for (c = 0; c < (numbers - 1); c++)
    {
        min = c;

        for (d = c + 1; d < numbers; d++){
            if (array[min] > array[d])
                min = d;
        }
        if (min != c){
            temp = array[c];
            array[c] = array[min];
            array[min] = temp; 
        }
    }
 
    //Sorting result
    printf("Hasil:");
    for(k=0; k<numbers; k++){
        printf("%d ", array[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Please help me if you understand. **Thank you so much!**

Comment: So. Keep the count associated with each number and increment it each time the number is swapped.

Comment: `case` is a C keyword.  Therefore, it should not be used as a variable name.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding:  (the compiler does not care)  Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: are you saying that your posted code does not produce results?  That is because there is no call to `printf()` to output the number and the count of swaps.  Or are you saying the posted code does not produce the correct results?

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding:  Please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  There are several variables that are used but never declared.  Each of these undeclared variables is an error.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: If, for example, more than one array entry has the same number of maximum swaps,  do you want to tell the user about all those numbers, or only the first number, or the last number?  Please clarify